# Jenkins multi branch pipeline not triggered on deployment event

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline, github-webhook

I have setup a job as a multi branch pipeline and I want to trigger it on a deployment event from **github**, but nothing happens when I do that.

**Jenkins** manages the webhooks automatically. 
The deployment checkbox on the webhook is marked, and When I try it for other events such as `tag` `merge` `push` `pull` `request` etc... it works.

Can anybody please help ?

Comment: Jenkins **git** Webhook is triggered when a **git** event is performed: tag merge push pull request. What do you mean with "a deployment event from github"? As I know, there is not a git event called "deploy". You are talking about : git actions?

Comment: If you'll look inside the webhook on github you'll see an event called deployment